# A WCF Service Method can be executed in the UI thread as with a StandardOleMarshalObject?

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, user-interface, ole

I'm developing an addin for a commercial application to expose very simple informations about document opened in that application and so on. The applications itself don't support COM or NET addin but only C++ addin in a DLL.

I want to expose some informations to COM clients and some informations NET clients running in the same machine.

For COM clients I developed in C# an implementation of a COM interface; then I create an object when the host application start and I register the object in the Running Object Table. Deriving this implementation from `StandardOleMarshalObject` appear sufficient to solve threading issue: apparently the methods of my implementation are called only on main UI thread at message boundary, which is a requirement.

And for NET clients? I need different informations and I don't need to rely on a specific COM interface to expose these information. I was tempted to develop and host a WCF service, but my service methods are called on non-UI therad and the host application crash. How can I replicate the `StandardOleMarshalObject` behavior in a WCF context? I need to implement an `IOperationInvoker`? Any suggestion to do **this**?

Thanks to all and please excuse my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `SynchronizationContext` to advance processing to the UI thread. You can explicitly call `SynchronizationContext.Send` in each service operation implementation or, if there are many operations to implement, you can implement posting to sync context as aspect in  `IOperationInvoker`.

Comment: Thanks @ilya.dorofeev for your suggestion. I need to _use_ an already existing implementation of `SynchronizationContex` or I need to derive from `SynchronizationContex` and _implement_ a new `SynchronizationContex`? Apparently I cannot _use_ existing Windows Form and WPF `SynchronizationContex` because host application is not Windows Form or WPF. The main thread of the hosting application, when execute my plugin initialization code, has a `null` `SynchronizationContex`...

Comment: What is your host application? WinForms and WPF implement its own SynchronizationContexts. To implement SynchronizationContext for your environment you should understand how to dispatch work items to UI thread.

Comment: The 3rd party host application is a Native C/C++ Windows Application: so no WinForm, no WPF...

Comment: I'm not aware of how StandardOleMarshalObject can dispatch call to UI thread, but apparently it work. It is possible to replicate this behavior for NET/WCF clients? How?

Comment: Maybe you should implement service as a wrapper above object that implements StandardOleMarshalObject? That object should do the real job.